# Intersection, union, and subtraction of nested sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So our book for class only talks about sets-within-sets for only a brief moment, and only gives the example of the empty set being an element of a set of the empty set (If A = {$\phi$} and B = {{$\phi$}} then A $\in$ B but A $\nsubseteq$ B).

But let's say that A = { 3, {4, 5}, 7, 8 }  and  B = {4, {5, 7}, 6, 8}.

What would A $\cap$ B be?
A $\cup$ B?
A - B?

My personal guesses -
Intersection: {8} ; 
Union: {3, {4,5}, {5,7}, 6, 7, 8} ; 
A - B: {3, {4,5}, 7}

Comment: Missed a $4$ in your union but looks good otherwise.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that, for example, $4$ and $\{4,5\}$ are _completely different_ elements of the sets, and they appear (or not) in the unions and differences independently of each other. For the purpose of these operations you can choose to write $*$ instead of $\{4,5,\}$ and completely forget that it happens to have a $4$ somewhere inside of it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I really like the substitution for a symbol idea. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$A \cap B = \{x : x \in A \;\text{ and }\; x\in B \} \\
A \cup B = \{x : x \in A \;\text{ or }\; x\in B \} \\
A - B = \{x: x \in A \; \text{and} \; x\not\in B \}. $$

---

In particular, if $A = \{ 3, \{4, 5\}, 7, 8 \}$ and $B = \{4, \{5, 7\}, 6, 8\}$, then we have that $$A \cap B = \{8\} \\
A \cup B = \{3,4,6,7,8,\{4,5\},\{5,7\}\} \\
A - B = \{3,\{4,5\},7\}.   
$$

Comment: Why do we count the elements of the nested sets as elements within the top level set in union? I don't understand they would be relevant outside their set.

Comment: @dopps You don't. As I mention in comment to OP, you missed a $4$ (from the set $B$) in the union.

Comment: @JohnHabert Thanks for the confirmation and your comment. Cheers!